# Select most occurring values across few fields after GROUP BY in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table with few fields, e.g. A, B, C, D

I need to group by field A, and select most occuring values from B, C, D.

Example:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| A | B | C | D  |
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 15 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 32 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 34 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 50 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 2 | 8 | 1 | 32 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

Expected result:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| A | B | C | D  |
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 15 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 50 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

I saw a lot of examples how to select most occurring value from one column by using COUNT(*) and than using MAX on top of that. But what to do in this case ?

Comment: what should you do in case of ties?

Comment: doesn't matter, I guess select first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query looks a bit complicated because you have to do it for 3 columns. The idea is to rank the rows by counts grouping by combinations of a-b,a-c,a-d and getting the first row for each combination. This is done using variables. In case of ties for counts the lowest value of b,c or d is returned. (this can be changed if the ordering needs to be reversed.) Finally one more aggregation is required to get corresponding values on to one row.

[`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5503c6/27)

```
select a,max(b),max(c),max(d)
from (
select a,b,c,d 
from (select a,b,c,d,
      @rn:=case when @prev=a then @rn+1 else 1 end as rank,
      @prev:=a
      from (select a,b,null as c,null as d,count(*) as cnt
            from tbl
            group by a,b
           ) t
      cross join (select @rn:=0,@prev:='') r
      order by a,cnt desc,b
     ) t
where rank = 1
union all
select a,b,c,d 
from (select a,b,c,d,
      @rn:=case when @prev=a then @rn+1 else 1 end as rank,
      @prev:=a
      from (select a,null as b,c,null as d,count(*) as cnt
            from tbl
            group by a,c
           ) t
      cross join (select @rn:=0,@prev:='') r
      order by a,cnt desc,c
     ) t
where rank = 1
union all
select a,b,c,d
from (select a,b,c,d,
      @rn:=case when @prev=a then @rn+1 else 1 end as rank,
      @prev:=a
      from (select a,null as b,null as c,d,count(*) as cnt
            from tbl
            group by a,d
           ) t
      cross join (select @rn:=0,@prev:='') r
      order by a,cnt desc,d
     ) t
where rank = 1
) t
group by a
```

Comment: thank you.

this query is quite complex, but at least it works :)